# How to parse XMPP?

Tags: c#, xml, stream, xmpp

Anybody knows how to parse XMPP-stream in the right way in C#?
I had problem with malformed XML in XMPP, because you didn't get `</stream>` tag, until end of stream(connection) and how to handle namespaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to parse it your self for some reason? Can't you use dedicated library like [agsXMPP](http://www.ag-software.net/agsxmpp-sdk/) ?

Comment: I've tried it before, but I can't use it because agsXMPP isn't works in WP8.1 (Cannot find type System.Collections.CollectionBase in module mscorlib.dll). I'm trying to use XMPP in WP8.1 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when using standard TCP transport for XMPP you does not have proper "framing". [XMLReader.ReadSubTree()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx) for the rescue! Basically:

1. create XMLReader instance and do `MoveToContent`
2. do `Read` while `XMLReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element`
3. do `ReadSubtree` and use newly created `XMLReader` as the whole next XML Element, e.g. you can use `XElement.Load` from XML to LINQ and get pretty `XElement` instance.

Alternatively, you can use [Websocket XMPP transport](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7395) where each "frame" is `XMLNode`/`XElement` without unclosed opening stream element